# Response.redirect kills local storage?

Tags: html, persistence, local-storage

I am trying to work with `HTML5` local storage in asp. I can read and write to the storage, but if I do  a `response.redirect` the entire local storage is wiped out?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

localStorage["email"] = "<%=email%>";

localStorage["remember"] = "1";
</script>
```

This works fine for saving and I can see the variable saved in local storage using Developer Tools.

However if after that I add

```
 response.redirect ("index.asp")
```

then the entire local storage is cleaned. How can I cause to to persist?

Comment: So are you saying that you redirect to a page on the same domain and the data has dissapeared?

Comment: Kinda weird... suposedly localStorage should remain even after leaving site or closing browser. Maybe you are redirecting to a page where localStoreage is being cleaned?

Comment: That is correct - it simply disappears on the next page. For example if all i have is an asp page with the code above without the last line (response.redirect), everything works and i can read the localstorage and it is still there. However if I add the last line and try to read localstorage on the next page, it is empty. Even if index.asp is a blank page which just reads local storage it comes out empty. Also the local storage is not being cleaned. I tried changing localstorage to cookies and everything works fine, but it does not with localstorage. I cant understand it...

Comment: I know this is a hack but try adding a short delay before redirecting

Comment: Tested it Response.Redirect kills Local storage

Answer (score 6):

The problem is (as Neil suggests) that localStorage takes a few milliseconds to execute and that you're redirecting before the process is complete. I had a similar problem with a javascript redirect after setting something in localStorage.
You're using ASP so (and I can't say for sure without seeing more of the code) but if I remember correctly ASP is parsed on the Server so you're redirecting before *any* javascript executes.

Try using this instead:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

localStorage["email"] = "<%=email%>";

localStorage["remember"] = "1";

setTimeout(function(){
   location.href = "index.asp";
},100)
```

Comment: Got exactly this problem. Unbeliavably. Why even JS executes assignment to localStorage asynchronously?